# How to blend images using a mask in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I have two images `img1` and `img2` of type `CV_8UC3` and a `mask` of type `CV_8UC1`.

All matrices have values in the range 0-255. I want to calculate the result of:

```
mask_ .* img1 + (1.0 - mask_) * img2
```

where `mask_ = mask / 255.0`.

How to do this correctly? If I need the intermediate `mask_`, what's its type/declaration?

Comment: you can use filter2D and addweight functions of Opencv.

Comment: `mask_.mul(img1) + (1.0 - mask_).mul(img2);`

Comment: How do I declare mask_?

Comment: `Mat mask_; mask.converTo(mask_, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0 `. You then probably need to blend each channel separately (see `cv::split` and `cv::merge`)

Comment: each channel must be computed separately and maybe img1 and img2 must be CV_32F format, too. I would compute the per-pixel blending manually in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a built-in  way to do this, here is what I use:

```
cv::Mat weightedBlend(const cv::Mat &img1, const cv::Mat &img2, const cv::Mat &mask) {
    assert((img1.type() == CV_8UC1 && img2.type() == CV_8UC1) ||
           (img1.type() == CV_8UC3 && img2.type() == CV_8UC3));
    assert(mask.type() == CV_8UC1);
    assert(img1.rows == mask.rows && img1.cols == mask.cols);
    assert(img2.rows == mask.rows && img2.cols == mask.cols);

    cv::Mat res(img1.rows, img1.cols, img1.type());
    const int nChannels = img1.channels();

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < mask.rows; ++iRow) {
        const uchar *pImg1Row = img1.ptr<uchar>(iRow);
        const uchar *pImg2Row = img2.ptr<uchar>(iRow);
        const uchar *pMaskRow = mask.ptr<uchar>(iRow);
        uchar *pResRow = res.ptr<uchar>(iRow);

        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < mask.cols; ++iCol) {
            float w = pMaskRow[iCol] / 255.0;
            for (int iChan = 0; iChan < nChannels; ++iChan) {
                int iChanElem = nChannels * iCol + iChan;
                pResRow[iChanElem] = roundf(w * pImg1Row[iChanElem] + (1-w) * pImg2Row[iChanElem]);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the contents of `img1` to `img2` and give a mask to copy only the regions that are covered by the mask:

```
img1.copyTo(img2, mask);
```

Afterwards `img2` contains the mix between `img1` and `img2`

Comment: But the mask here is binary, it will treat 1 and 255 values the same (i.e. it only matters if the mask pixel is zero or non-zero)